# Add array values with key to multidimensional array without adding a new 'layer'

Tags: php, arrays

I have found several similar topics but none answers exactly what I need. I want to add data to a specific key index of a multidiensional array - without adding a new array layer or deleting other array layers.

I have tried to solve it with array_merge and the normal add to array method.

This is my array:

```
$array = [
    'capital' => [
        'Germany' => 'Berlin',
        'Austria' => 'Vienna',
        'France' => 'Paris',
    ],
    'currency' => [
        'Germany' => 'Euro',
        'Austria' => 'Euro',
        'France' => 'Euro',
    ],
 ];
```

If I try

```
$newData2 = [
    'Italy' => 'Rome',
    'China' => 'Beijing',
];
$array['capital'][] = $newData2;
```

I get

```
$array = [
    'capital' => [
        'Germany' => 'Berlin',
        'Austria' => 'Vienna',
        'France' => 'Paris',
        [
            'Italy' => 'Rome',
            'China' => 'Beijing',
        ],
    ],
    'currency' => [
        'Germany' => 'Euro',
        'Austria' => 'Euro',
        'France' => 'Euro',
    ],
 ];
```

That's incorrect, the 2 new should be on the same array layer as the others.

If I use array_merge, the currency section of the array is deleted:

```
 array_merge($array['capital'], $newData2);
```

My array should look like this:

```
$array = [
    'capital' => [
        'Germany' => 'Berlin',
        'Austria' => 'Vienna',
        'France' => 'Paris',
        'Italy' => 'Rome',
        'China' => 'Beijing',
    ],
    'currency' => [
        'Germany' => 'Euro',
        'Austria' => 'Euro',
        'France' => 'Euro',
    ],
 ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $array['capital'] = array_merge($array['capital'], $newData2);

 print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 $array['capital']['Italy'] = 'Rome';
 $array['capital']['China'] = 'Beijing';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try just adding second array to the `capital` key:

```
$array["capital"] += $newData2;
```

I should add that there is a difference between `merge` and `+` operator, and you should use the one that fits better your needs.